# Start backup folders with background tasks UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-runtime, task

I have to start a backup of folders with background task so with an implememntazione of Component Windows Runtime but in Component Windows Runtime it is not possible to use public static async Task method.

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void BtnChooseFolder_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FolderPicker folderPicker = new FolderPicker();
        folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
        folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
        StorageFolder SelectFolderToLoad = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
        StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace("FolderToCopy", SelectFolderToLoad);
    }

    private async void BtnDestinationFolder_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FolderPicker folderPicker = new FolderPicker();
        folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
        folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
        StorageFolder SelectFolderToLoad = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
        StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace("DestinationFolder", SelectFolderToLoad);
    }

    private void BtnTask_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var cur in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
        {
            if (cur.Value.Name == "TaskLocalBackup")
            {
                cur.Value.Unregister(true);
            }
        }

        var requestTask = BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();

        var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();

        builder.Name = "TaskLocalBackup";
        builder.TaskEntryPoint = "ClassBackgraundTask.BackgroundTaskClass";
        //builder.SetTrigger(new SystemTrigger(SystemTriggerType.UserPresent, false));

        builder.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(15, false));

        BackgroundTaskRegistration task = builder.Register();
    }
```

BackgroundTaskClass.cs: (In Component Windows Runtime)

```
    public sealed class BackgroundTaskClass : IBackgroundTask
    {
        public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            StartBackup();
        }
        private async static void StartBackup()
        {
            StorageFolder folderToSave = await 
                  StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFolderAsync("FolderToCopy");
            StorageFolder foldersSaved = await        
                 StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFolderAsync("DestinationFolder");
            await CopyFolderAsync(folderToSave, foldersSaved);
        }

        public static async Task CopyFolderAsync(StorageFolder source, StorageFolder destinationContainer)
        {
            StorageFolder destinationFolder = null;
            destinationFolder = await destinationContainer.CreateFolderAsync("Local" ?? source.Name, 
                                CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

            foreach (var file in await source.GetFilesAsync())
            {
                await file.CopyAsync(destinationFolder, file.Name, 
                      NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            }
            foreach (var folder in await source.GetFoldersAsync())
            {
                 await CopyFolderAsync(folder, destinationFolder);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the error:

> Method 'ClassBackgraundTask.BackgroundTaskClass.CopyFolderAsync(Windows.Storage.StorageFolder, Windows.Storage.StorageFolder)' has a parameter of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' in its signature.  Although this type is not a valid Windows Runtime type, it implements interfaces that are valid Windows Runtime types.  Consider changing the method signature to use one of the following types instead: 'System.IDisposable'.   ClassBackgraundTask

How can it be resolved?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should not be writing a bacakup programm yourself. There are literal dozens of Backup Programms out there. Heck, on a Windows I could do it with Robocopy. Indeed I often do make backups with Robocopy.

Comment: These easiest solution is to make `CopyFolderAsync` `private`, but you will need to use a deferral for your `taskInstance`.